# How to rollback the two previous commits?

Tags: git, github, reset

Consider this scenario:

1. Developer A does a commit: **#n**
2. Dev. B does commit **#n+1**
3. Dev. A does commit **#n+2**
4. and commit **#n+3**

and then discovers that in his commit #n+2 he introduced a defect.

How can dev. A rollback his last 2 commits and continue developing on commit **#n+1**?

Tried `git reset --hard HEAD~2`[*](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset), but it's coming back to dev A's commit **#n**.

Comment: git reset HEAD~2 should reset to #n+1 commit if you have pulled B commits at that point. Did you pulled them?

Comment: ...not before #n+2 commit. It was: [0] B pushed `commit` #n+1, [1] A `commit`ted #n+2, [2] unsuccessful `push`, [3] `pull`, [4] `push`. So on github now there is a commit (#n+2), and a Merge branch 'master' (#n+3).

Comment: If you have already published the commit, you should not use reset to roll it back.  (If some other developer unkown to you has pulled, this will cause pain.)  Instead, use revert and make a new commit that brings you to the state that you want.  Never change a published history.  See http://book.git-scm.com/4_undoing_in_git_-_reset,_checkout_and_revert.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to undo last commit(s) in Git?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/927358/how-to-undo-last-commits-in-git)

Answer (score 163, accepted):

It should come back to the n+1 commit. You probably have a merge commit in there as well. You can also do a `git reset --hard <sha1_of_where_you_want_to_be>`

> WARNING!! `--hard` means that any uncommitted changes you currently have
>   will be thrown away permanently.

Comment: How do I get the sha1 of a remote commit (not done by me)?
I tried using `git reflog`, but I can only access my local reflog information e.g, commits #n, #n+2, #n+3... but not #n+1

Comment: I got the sha1 I wanted from a `git log`, but a `git push -f` was also required, so the modifications would be reflected on github.

Comment: Yes but I didn't know you wanted to update a remote as well :)

Comment: your answer was very helpful nevertheless, therefore being the accepted one too. :)

Comment: WARNING!! `--hard` means that any uncommitted changes you currently have will be thrown away permanently. To roll back to a previous commit w/o throwing away your work, use `--soft`.

Comment: Please explain the use of --hard instead of --soft

Comment: @KenM.Haggerty Warning about warning - you (almost) never *really* throw anything away in git.. learn about reflog and getting things back. But yes, it's better to admit your mistakes clearly.

Comment: @MariusButuc as you say `git push -f` then required to overwrite the HEAD on the remote branch.

Comment: woooooorks!!!!!!

Answer (score 30):

I would suggest using instead something like this:

```
git reset --soft <commit_hash>
```

Unless you want it to remove all the changes up to that point, in that case use --hard instead of --soft, it would get you to the desired point in the tree WITHOUT trowing away all of the changes made in the commits.

While I was reading I tried with --HARD and for my misfortune, it removed all my changes up to that point. So, pay attention to whether you want them removed or not.

so, if you are unlucky as me try this! : `git revert <commit_hash>`

Comment: This answer was more helpful than the accepted answer because when I undo changes its usually because I've committed work on the wrong branch. `--soft` is better since I can always delete the files if I so choose.

Comment: Agreed. If you use `--soft`, you can then switch branches and your working directory changes still exist, so you can then do with them whatever you like.

Comment: This answer was what I was looking for. I reverted my local commit and got my files also. Gave an upvote even though the answer is something else.